# which it is the best way to create a desktop windows app with HTML, CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, desktop

I want to start with desktop development, i am student and i have been working on web development, searching i found some tools and frameworks

- AppJS
- Node-Webkit
- Titanium
- Sciter
- Awesomium
- chromiumembedded

And others... I don't know which one I must use, i don´t want to have problems in the future, so I need the better one with great support and functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We use Electron as container for web based multiplatform app
http://electron.atom.io
And the container is that must to have for desktop applications written in html + js + css. Electron is similar to node-webkit (nw) you mentioned.